# Delete a row based on cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make a script that deletes all rows that have a 0 in a specific cell. Then I would like to export that sheet as a CSV. I would like to tie that back to a button that I have on another sheet. I am a beginner when it comes to writing scripts, the problem that I am running into is that the document is being saved from a template so the file ID is always changing. The folder ID that I want the file exported to does not change. I have spent weeks on this trying different things, and I have yet to get it to work.

Any help with this at all would be greatly apricated!!

I have tried many things and have yet to come up with a solution.

This is what I have for the delete function and it is working. I am just having trouble with the export as CSV.

```
function deleteRows() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('roof quote')
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[4] == '0') { // This searches all cells in columns A 
(change to row[1] for columns B and so on) and deletes row if it 
has value '0'.
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I am trying to make a script that deletes all rows that have a 0 in a specific cell. Then I would like to export that sheet as a CSV. I would like to tie that back to a button that I have on another sheet.`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide your current script, the current issue of your script, and the detail of your goal?

Comment: The script that have now that deletes the cells is in my edit and it is working. What I am having trouble with now is getting the CSV file to export when I click the button.

Comment: One topic per question. I suggest you create a new question dealing specifically with the export as a csv.

Answer (score 1):

```
function deleteRowsThatHaveVInColumnN(n=1,v = 1) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName");
  const sr = 2; //data start row
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr,1,sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1,sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const d = 0;
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(r[n-1] === v ) {
      sh.deleteRow(i + sr - d++);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I ended up getting the delete function to work. Now the CSV part

Comment: I didn't see the CSV part and I don't wish to do it.